# Laravel hasOneThrough(); intermediary table custom column value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, has-one-through

I sincerely apologize if this question has been answered before, however I didn't seem to find a similar situation elsewere. If it is a duplicate, please point me to the right direction.

I have three custom tables:

```
> app_expressions;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| expression | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bot        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

> app_links;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| source      | varchar(10)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| destination | varchar(10)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sid         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| did         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| bot         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

> app_replies;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| reply | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bot   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`app_expressions` is connected to `app_replies` through `app_links`

---

Suppose I have a single record in each table.

- `app_expressions.id` is the same as in `app_links.sid` where `app_links.source = 'expression'`
- `app_replies.id` is the same as in `app_links.did` where `app_links.destination = 'reply'`

---

Using Laravel's `hasOneThrough()` how can I access `app_expressions`'s reply from `app_replies` through `app_links` with condition `app_links.destination = 'reply'`? Pseudocode below:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Expressions extends Model
{
    /*
    *   Table
    */
    protected $table = 'app_expressions';

    /*
    *   Get all replies linked with this record
    */
    public function get_reply()
    {
        return $this -> hasOneThrough(
            'App\Replies',
            'App\Links',
            'did',  // Destination ID
            'id',  
            'id',
            'sid'   // Source ID
        ) -> where('intermediary table.destination', '=', 'reply') ;
    }
}
```

I hope I explained it well.

Comment: If you need to fetch `reply` through `links`  reply should have link_id , if you want to use `hasOneThrough`

Comment: @AnoopD It's not necessarily. We can configure column names manually, which I did.

Comment: i was not talking about the name of column , but `app_replies` should contain `app_links.id`

Comment: @AnoopD You're right. Although relationship still works for my case; I've tested it in tinker: `Expressions::first() -> get_reply` returns the correct result. What am I missing? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I had to use pivot table specific methods. Here's the code for reference.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Expressions extends Model
{
    /*
    *   Table
    */
    protected $table = 'app_expressions';

    /*
    *   Get all replies linked with this record
    */
    public function get_reply()
    {
        return $this -> belongsToMany(
                            'App\Replies', // The destination table (app_replies)
                            'app_links',  // The pivot table; It can take a Model as argument as well (app_links)
                            'sid',        // Foreign key on pivot table (app_expressions.id on app_links.sid)
                            'did',        // Wanted key on pivot table (app_replies.id on app_links.did)
                            'id',         // Foreign key (app_expressions.id)
                            'id'          // Wanted key (app_replies.id)
                        )         

                        -> wherePivot('destination', 'reply'); // app_links.destination = 'reply'

    }
```

**Philosophy:** I'm accessing records from `app_replies`, through `app_links`, using `app_expressions`, if `app_links.sid = app_expressions.id` and `app_links.destination = 'reply'`. Tested code for tinker below:

```
$app = new App\Expressions;

$expression = $app -> first();

$reply = $expression -> get_reply;
```

---

For further information I recommend seeking the parameters of methods declared on `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany\HasRelationship`

Answer (score 0):

in you code when querying you can use **WhereHas** to filter your table based on Through table filter for example:

```
$str='reply';
$data=Expressions::whereHas('get_reply',function($q) use($str){
$q->where('app_links.destination',$str);
})->get();
```

and don't forgot remove this line on Expressions model :

```
-> where('intermediary table.destination', '=', 'reply') ;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I receive `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'app_links.' in 'where clause'`

Comment: It still doesn't work. This only returns the expression, not the reply/replies.

I also tried `Expressions::first() -> whereHas('get_reply',function($q) use($str){
$q->where('app_links.destination',$str);
})->get();` it still doesn't work. It returns only the expression not the reply assigned to it.

Comment: you can access the reply as property : $data->get_reply

Comment: Still it's not what I need. I need to access the linked reply based on what value `app_links.destination` has. `$data->get_reply` works for one record, but not for others with mixed IDs